# Line up adjacent DIVs vertically without forced <BR>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yL9b2ewu/1/

In this fiddle I have 3 DIVs using Bootstrap 3.3.7 that are next to each other; each DIV is `col-sm-3`.

Each DIV contains a fixed-size button, then there should be a small amount of space under the button, and then optional explanatory text. Each DIV should end with a border at the same level as the lowest available DIV regardless of whether it has text or not.

One solution is to hard-code some `<BR>`s for the explanation section. In the 3rd DIV I could put in 4 fixed `<BR>`s. But this hackery doesn't seem right to me, there should be something dynamic and robust.

```
                 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; font-size: 14px">                        
                    <div class="col-sm-4 cardstyle">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btnSubmitWizard"><b>Submit Recall Now<br><br></b></button>
                        <br><br>No changes can be made after the recall is submitted.
        <!-- Can Insert <BR> here but wrong approach -->
                    </div>                       

                    <div class="col-sm-4 cardstyle">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnSubmitWizard"><b>Review and Edit<br><br></b></button>
                        <br><br>Review or edit timeline before submitting.
        <!-- Can Insert <BR> here but wrong approach -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4 cardstyle">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnSubmitWizard"><b>Logout and<br>Submit Later </b></button>
        <br><br>
                        <!-- Can Insert <BR> here but wrong approach -->
                    </div>                          
                </div>
```

Comment: you can override bootstrap3 style (the floatting) via a mediaquerie and reset a display . If you choose bootsrap3 to mind old browser, display:table/table-cell will do *(IE8 understood it)*  : https://jsfiddle.net/drz2xegv/  not sure you looked to add a mediaquerie and styles not from bootsrap classes

Comment: Thanks great comment, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Give a class for the parent of the columns. Something like `.colsParent`.
Then, for the same breakpoint of Bootstrap `@media`, you set flexbox for this element.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .colsParent {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

By default, it fills the full height of the entire column.

Do not set `display: flex` inline, because it will affect the layout for devices smaller than the breakpoint above.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could select only the last div using [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) and add to it a bigger padding-bottom.

Comment: But ideally I shouldn't depend on position to specify this property. It should be dynamically whatever needs some extra length.